# DevExpress XtraReport in ASP.NET MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, xtrareport

This is my first time trying to create a DevExpress XtraReport in ASP.NET MVC 4 C#.  I've followed the VERY simple example given on the DevExpress site:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument9974

Of course, this is a very simple example that doesn't use any data.  How would I modify this example to include data from the database that I'm using in my application?  To make things simple, let's say that I have a FireCode model like below to a table in the database with the typical default controller.  All I want to do is create a report that lists all the fire codes in the database.  This is as simple a report that I can think of, but I don't know how to set it up within ASP.NET MVC 4 using the example that DevExpress gave:

```
public class FireCode
{
    public int FireCodeId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Sincerely,

Gregg

Comment: Did you try this? http://search.devexpress.com/?q=XtraReport&p=T4%7cP14%7c0&d=144

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. The easiest, if you just want to create a report based on a table, is to use the built in DevExpress GridView DataExport function, illustrated here:
https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Exporting/Export

If, however, you want to use the XtraReports functionality, you could follow this example:
https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxReportDemos/ReportTypes/TableReport

I hope this helps!